# 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 428 not upgraded

Tags: software-installation

When I want to install libqtcore4 or libqtgui4 or even libqt4-xml I got this text

```
maryam@maryam-MM061:~$ sudo apt-get install libqtcore4
[sudo] password for maryam: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqtcore4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 428 not upgraded.
```

I work with ubuntu 12.10
Thanks

Comment: In fact, what is your question? Or you just wanted to tell us that you get some text when you want to install something from terminal? ...We know about this.

Comment: @Alvar I delete my answer, because I realized that does not respond to anything... there is no question.

Comment: why do you have to be so mean? The OP is obviously new to Ubuntu and doesn't understand the terminal as good as we do.

Answer (score 8):

The lines actually say that `libqtcore4` is already installed and is the newest version.

But it also says that you have 428 updates to install. Open the update manage with `update-manager` or type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade your system. `dist-upgrade` installs new kernels and such it does not install a newer release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank alot. Is it possible to ask you something about VTK INSTALLATION?

Comment: @user196345 Ask a new question if it's about something else, also accept my answer if it solved your question. thanks :)

Comment: As you said I'm new and very very unfamiliar with ubuntu. and my question. I have to install vtk5.10 on my ubuntu with the following options VTK_USE_GUISUPPORT; VTK_USE_QT;VTK_USE_QTCHARTS;VTK_USE_RENDERING

Comment: VTK_USE_GUISUPPORT sounds like the best for you, but I've never used this package so this is just my guess.

Comment: As you said I'm new and very very unfamiliar with ubuntu. and my question.I find out that I can't ask my question. because it is very long. If it is possible for you please search "VTK INSTALLATION ERROR" in ASKUBUNTU. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That means you already have the software/package installed on your computer.